# How can I set dependencies on child resources in nested ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to use nested templates to deploy a resource group and multiple resources within it on subscription level.

Microsoft documentation has an [example of deploying resource group and storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli#create-resource-group-and-resources) that I'm trying to follow. I am trying to create another inner level of dependency between a Storage Account resource and a Container resource. That is, the container should only be deployed after the deployment of the storage account is finished. Here is simplified version of my template:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rgName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "rgLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storagePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 11
    },
    "containerName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageName": "[concat(parameters('storagePrefix'), uniqueString(subscription().id, parameters('rgName')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "storageDeployment",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
              "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
              },
              "kind": "StorageV2"
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
              "apiVersion": "2021-06-01",
              "name": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', variables('storageName'), parameters('containerName'))]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "outputs": {}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

When I try to deploy this template using PowerShell script `New-AzSubscriptionDeployment`, I get the following error:

```
|  InvalidTemplate - Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/myStorageAccount' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.'
```

I kind of know it has to do with the `dependsOn` part of the container resource. But how can I resolve this problem?

---

EDIT: The selected answer solves the problem with dependencies, however the issue still persists in cases where a value needs to be called using `concat` or `listKeys` expressions. Here's an example where setting the value for `AzureWebJobsStorage` throws an error in a nested template:

```json
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    [ ... ]
    "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
        "[variables('functionAppStorageAccountName')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('functionAppstorageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('functionAppstorageAccountName')), '2021-04-01').keys[0].value)]"
                }
                [ ... ]
            ]
        }
```

The value for `AzureWebJobsStorage` causes the deployment to fail with the following error:

```
`Status Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stfuncaedotestfeb16g' under resource group '<null>' was not found. For more details
     | please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix (Code:ResourceNotFound)  CorrelationId: 55942377-6d0f-40ec-9733-33b9c3ea13de
```

I tried being more verbose by using resource group name (and then subscription ID), but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
"dependsOn": [
  "[variables('storageName')]"
]
```

Note that will only work if there is no other resource in the template with the same name - otherwise you have to manually construct the full resourceId, like:

```
[format('{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{2}', subscription().id, parameters('rgName'), variables('storageName'))]
```

The latter form will always work, just a bit more verbose.

A bit more detail is that the resourceId function doesn't work as you would expect at subscription scope.

Comment: Removing resourceType and using only the `storageName` variable fixed it for me, thanks! I was able to make similar changes to all other dependant resources. However in the `AzureWebJobStorage`, I'm still having issues with getting `AccountKey` as it uses listKeys: `listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('functionAppstorageAccountName')), '2021-04-01').keys[0].value`. Couldn't get it to work by removing resourceType or using the `verbose` path.

Comment: Can you share the code and the error?

Comment: Sure, I edited the original question.

Comment: the "new" problem is from listKeys (not concat) - there's a scheduling issue in the deployment engine where that call is made sooner than it should be - there is a workaround for it: https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/